# React Native Input not allowing edit value

Tags: react-native, native-base

I created an Input using native base, but I can't edit the value. It keep showing the same value.

```
render() {
    const {
      FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Unit, MiddleName
    } = this.state.MyData;
    ...
    <Input
        value={LastName}
        onChangeText={val => this.setState({ LastName: val })}
        style={styles.valueText}
   />
   ...
```

It has the value 'Smith'. When I click on the Input, it does not allow me to delete or add characters.

Thanks

Comment: you are not updating the object `this.state.MyData` but `LastName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the object but adding a new value to state, after typing a value into the Input your state becomes.

```
state = {
 MyData: {...},
 LastName: ...
}
```

Update the object instead

```
onChangeText = (text, input) => {
  const obj = { ...this.state.MyData };

  obj[input] = text;

  this.setState({
    MyData: obj
  })
};


<Input
  value={LastName}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'LastName')}
  style={styles.valueText}
/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this onChangeText reusable? I'm, I would like to use it for LastName, FirstName, Email...

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 yes, please see my updated answer. change the function to take the second parameter, which will be the property you want to change.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Please take a look at my snack: https://snack.expo.io/BJWsnDM-S Why is it creating a huge space between one item to another. Also, when I click on edit one field, it is cutting off the first letters.

Comment: @JuniusL. When I try this, I get _this2.onChangeText is not a function when I try to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

now you can use code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```